# How do i have the report footer ONLY appear on last page in Reporting Services?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report footer that i want to appear on the last page only of my report.  I have the option selected that says 'Print on Last Page' as True.  I also have the option to print on first page as false.  However, when i have an invoice say 4 pages long, the footer shows up on all the last three pages.

thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try placing the content at the end of your report, making sure it is outside of any grouping object (list, matrix, table).

If the content is at the end of the report, it will always be on the last page and only the last page.  No footer or special group is needed.

You can position it on the last page by leaving some empty space between the content you want at the end and the rest of the report.  Check your report height and width settings.

Good luck.